# Can't change variable in Event

Tags: android, oop, kotlin, gesturedetector

Try to detect swipe gesture and use code from android docs with liitle changes.
I try to show toast with Y-axis data. I was declared variable in the beginning of MyGestureListener class and try to change it, when onFling method called. I want to show toast with Y-axis data, but always see default string "Def_Nothing". If I add Log.d — I watch, that onFling method working and I get correct data of X and Y axis.
I think don't understood some fundamental of object oriented programming and neen little explanation of it.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mDetector: GestureDetectorCompat

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, MyGestureListener())
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        val myGestureListener = MyGestureListener()
        Toast.makeText(this, myGestureListener.currentGesture, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    class MyGestureListener: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        var currentGesture: String = "Def_Nothing"

        override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {

            currentGesture = (e2!!.y - e1!!.y).toString()
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep a reference to your gesture listener, you cant just create a  new one every time. See the example code below.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mDetector: GestureDetectorCompat
    private lateinit var mGestureListener: MyGestureListener

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mGestureListener = MyGestureListener()
        mDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, mGestureListener)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        Toast.makeText(this, mGestureListener.currentGesture, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    class MyGestureListener: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.
I can't increase answer rate.
P.S. Will go to learn theory of OOP.

Comment: Glad to help you. You should [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.